# Removing spaces between numbers

Tags: python

I copied to python a number which was in a text file in several lines.
I assigned it to a variable, but it shows only the first line as the value of the variable.

Is there any keyword to assign the whole number to the variable deleting spaces? I tried with `split` and came up with removing only the last space.

Comment: Post code of what you tried so far.

Comment: try `.strip()`.

Comment: show code. There can be many different problems and we can read in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

if you tried reading from the text file using the `.readline()` method, it only reads a line from your text file. try using `.read()` to read the whole content or `.readlines()` to read each line and return it as a list which you can concatenate and cast it into an integer using the`int("string")` method.